# Typecast by parameter hints

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a custom class with a `__str__()` method, is it possible to automatically type cast an object of this type to a string parameter of a function with minimal intrusion? Ideally using type hints but a decorator might also work

For example, given the following code:

```
class Custom:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return name

def do_stuff(arg: str):
    return hash(arg)

my_custom_var = Custom('my_name')
do_stuff(my_custom_var)
```

I want `do_stuff` to return the hash of 'my_name'. Is this possible?

Comment: Type hints won't have any runtime effect unless you do something with the `__annotations__` yourself. If your only purpose of doing this is to make your class hashable, just implement a `__hash__` method.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, Python doesn't really convert types implicitely, it will only work if the function `hash` itself calls `str` on the object at some point.

You can write a decorator that will try and convert the arguments to `str`, but decorator is just a function wrapper, it will still need to call it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str()](https://www.journaldev.com/22460/python-str-repr-functions) on the object. This makes an implicit call to `__str__()` method, similar to print()

```
do_stuff(str(my_custom_var))
```